# How to filter from join table in ManytoMany relationship

Tags: jpa

I have below tables with ManyToMany relationship between User and Hotel :

User with attributes:
Userid
preferredRating

Hotel with attributes:
HotelId
Rating

Join table UserHotel with attributes:
Userid, hotelId

I need to do something like :

```
 select * from UserHotel , Hotel where user_id = 3 
   AND UserHotel.hotelid  = hotel.hotelid
```

How to filter by attribute userid in the join table using Criteria ?

Thank you

Comment: CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Hotel> cq = cb.createQuery(Hotel.class);
  
  Root<Hotel> hotelRoot = cq.from(Hotel.class);
  
  Join<Object, Object> join = hotelRoot.join("users");
  
  //filter on userid and rating

  cb.equal(  join table’s userid, user.getUserId() ) ;

Comment: I can put a condition on the User side of the table , I can say User.userID = 3 since three tables will by joined by JPA. But I am not sure how to do this. Thanks